# Wordpress page feed is not showing

Tags: android, wordpress, rss

I have to develop an Android native app of a WordPress site in which there are only 5-6 typical pages which are rarely changed over time. There are no news section, comment section and other frequently updated section in the site.

http://multichoicesocial.com

So I wish to build an app which will parse the RSS feed to simply parse the contents and show inside the app.

My first question is - Is my decision best? or any better decision out there? i.e. JSON API plugin and parsing, XML-RPC or any other

For the RSS feed, I am seeking the link at http://multichoicesocial.com/twitter/feed/ .No problem with that, The link is showing RSS but the page content is not showing, rather than some few other texts. I also tried with other pages ( http://multichoicesocial.com/page_name/feed/ ) to get RSS like

1. http://multichoicesocial.com/twitter/feed/
2. http://multichoicesocial.com/facebook-customization/feed/
3. http://multichoicesocial.com/about-us/ and so on

But instead of showing the page content, all these are showing some dummy contents.

As the wordpress site is not developed by me, I saw the `page.php` to get any fault which might stop it to render RSS feed properly:

```
<div id="content">

    <?php themeblvd_breadcrumbs(); ?>

    <?php the_post(); ?>

    <?php if( $themeblvd_theme_hints == 'true' ) : ?>
        <?php echo themeblvd_theme_hints('page'); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'themeblvd_pagetitle', true) != 'false' ) : ?>
    <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <div class="page">

        <div class="top"><!-- --></div>

        <?php the_content(); ?>

        <?php edit_post_link( __('Edit Page', 'themeblvd'), '<p>', '</p>' ); ?>

        <div class="clear"></div>

        <div class="bottom"><!-- --></div>

    </div><!-- .page (end) -->

</div><!-- #content (end) -->

<?php if($themeblvd_sidebar == 'right') : ?>
    <?php get_sidebar(); ?> 
<?php endif; ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

But found nothing problematic. What's going on? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I installed **WordPress JQuery API** plugin and managed to see feed. :)